# 1004 Pastespecial of range failed

Tags: excel, vba

For days, this error happens randomly when copy and paste. I searched the internet and tried different approaches but still couldn't figure it out.

I just added `on error resume next` after the statement as a temporary fix and the program seems just runs fine, but what exactly caused this?

```
iRow = wsDest.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
lColumn = wsSource.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For sRow = 2 To wsSource.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For iCol = 1 To lColumn
      wsDest.Cells(iRow, iCol) = wsSource.Cells(sRow, iCol)
      wsSource.Cells(sRow, iCol).Copy

      wsDest.Cells(iRow, iCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     ' On Error Resume Next

    Next iCol
    wsDest.Cells(iRow, lColumn + 1) = Left(sFile, 6)

    iRow = iRow + 1

Next sRow
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only need this...

```
lColumn = wsSource.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For sRow = 2 To wsSource.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(sRow, 1), wsSource.Cells(sRow, lColumn)).Copy
    wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next sRow
```

Or just this. No need to loop through rows and columns.

```
lRow = wsSource.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
lColumn = wsSource.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

wsSource.Range("A2", wsSource.Cells(lRow, lColumn)).Copy
wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought about copy and paste the whole range but I still have to add one extra column, so I haven't figured out the right code yet(newbie here)

Comment: So the cutcopymode only clear the clipboard, right? not the variables in memory, right? It seemed when I used it previously, the program failed to find the file name...maybe my code was wrong somewhere else, not something to do with cutcopymode...

Comment: strange...I tried wsSource.usedrange.offset(1).copy previously, but this method failed

Comment: I think you should make up your mind first to decide what's your requirement actually.

Comment: the requirements are copy the sheets into one and with one extra column for user name.

Comment: strange...I use the following code and things got copied TWICE

Comment: wsSource.Range("A2", wsSource.Cells(iRow, lColumn)).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues